# Why can I suddenly not send emails to my contact groups in Outlook?

Tags: macos, email, contacts, microsoft-outlook-2011

I was able to send emails to my groups in Outlook and then suddenly about 6 weeks ago it stopped working. I get this message:

"EmailAddress or Itemid must be included in the request"

I haven't changed anything. It just stopped working.

Comment: Mac outlook?  there was ms update that caused that error if Mac outlook. Make sure you have everything updated. Microsoft's 14.3.2 update to Outlook 2011 for Mac, released March 12, 2013, causes this error.

Answer (score 3):

This has been resolved. Version 14.3.4 came out yesterday, May 7th and [fixed the error](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2830450):

> **Local group mail cannot be sent in Outlook for Mac**
>   Fixes an issues in which messages that are addressed to local contact groups in Outlook for Mac cannot be sent.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why this works, but I saw on one site that if you expand the list and double-click each person (to expand each entry to "name [e-mail]" where the square brackets are less-than and greater-than signs) and then hit Send, it'll send the message without error. I just did that now for a message I had this problem with, and it was sent. Something Microsoft did in an update messed up sending to an e-mail group, but this is the workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround until fix (Mac Outlook):

> Expand the Contact Group Listing
>         In the To (or Cc or Bcc) field where you've put the contact group, you'll see an icon of two downward-pointing arrows. Clicking
>   this icon will expand the group listing, displaying all the individual
>   email addresses that make up the group.
>
> Now, when you click Send, the message will be delivered as you expect.

Comment: Thank you for helping me! i tried tht and now i get this message:

Comment: "The message could not be sent because it has unresolved recipients."